# How to define Mock Cursor for Android Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, cursor, fragmentmanager

I fill the `Cursor` and `FragmentManager` value inside the `PageAdapter` class but during Test process it brings `Cursor` and `FragmentManager` as **null** for always.

How i can configure Test to get `Cursor` and `FragmentManager` with a valid value?

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
  private Cursor mCursor;

  public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor aCursor) {
    super(fm);
    mCursor = aCursor;
  }
```

Test code block is below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PagerAdapterTest extends Assert{
  @Mock
  private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

  private FragmentManager fm;
  private Cursor mCursor;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fm, mCursor);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: This code can **not** work! The references `fm` and `mCursor` will **not** change when you assign values to variables which are parameters of a method. This will break always, not only in your unit test. This simply fundamentally wrong on a basic java level.

Comment: I have to build and fill object for the `unit test`. I'm looking for a way to do this and I'm stucked :( Do you have a suggestion for me to fill in these objects?

Comment: Yes, I do not know enough about using the cursor at this stage. If I dominate the use of Cursor, I will write a reply under this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is "simple" - in your test code:

```
private FragmentManager fm;
private Cursor mCursor;
```

are both **null**. SO this:

```
mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fm, mCursor);
```

Maybe you assumed that @Mock mocks **all** fields - nope, sorry: it only mocks the *first* field declared afterwards!

So your code is just doing `new PageAdapter(null, null)`. The point is: you need to *mock* various core infrastructure elements that are provided by the Android system in the "real world".

And beyond that, you seem to *not understand* how mocking and unit tests come together. You want to **test** your PageAdapter class - and in that case it makes **no** sense to **mock** the PageAdapter class. You create mocks for those objects that you need to *feed* into your class under test to test that class. In that sense, you should *first* study the **basics** of unit testing and mocking (ideally *without* the complexity added by Android). Start reading [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) for example.

And then, when you "got that part", read and follow the *extensive* documentation that explains to you how to establish a "working" unit test environment for Android. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you, ghostcat, I'm reviewing the examples you specified.